# Pass mysql query as array to mysql In statement

Tags: mysql

I have a query like

```
UPDATE myproject.empinfo SET country="XYZ" WHERE emp_id = 2 order by stars desc limit 5 ;
SELECT id FROM myproject.emp where version = 'New'
```

What it will do is it sets the top 5 employee country to XYZ sorted by their stars.

But in this query I have given the emp_id to 2 ...I can do it for one emp easily but now I want a query that can update all empinfo for employee in emp table.

It should get ids of all emp as in my second query and make them an array like (1,2,3,..)

and pass it like

```
UPDATE myproject.empinfo SET country="XYZ" in($employeeIdarray) order by stars desc limit 5 ;
```

that employeeidarray should be the array of ids

How can I do this in one query?

Comment: Are you using PHP? It looks like you are with `$employeeIdarray`. If so, tag your question with the PHP tag, and use `implode(",", $employeeIdarray)` to comma separate your values.

Comment: no i want it to be done in mysql script

Comment: i need a mysql query for this that i can run in workbench

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) and comma separate them that way.

```
UPDATE myproject.empinfo 
SET country="XYZ" 
WHERE emp_id IN(select GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR ',') 
                  from myproject.emp 
                  where version = 'New') 
ORDER BY stars desc 
LIMIT 5;
```